# Matplotlib histogram, frequency as thousands

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, histogram

I have a histogram I'm drawing in matplotlib with some 260,000 values or so.

The problem is that the frequency axis (y axis) on the histogram reaches high numbers such as 100,000... What I'd really like is to have the y labels as thousands, so instead of, for instance:

> 100000
>
> 75000
>
> 50000
>
> 25000
>
> 0

To have this:

> 100
>
> 75
>
> 50
>
> 25
>
> 0

And then I can simply change the y axis to "Frequency (000s)" -- it makes it much easier to read that way. Anyone with any ideas how that can be achieved?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import numpy as np

mu, sigma = 100, 15
x = mu + sigma * np.random.randn(1000000)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
n, bins, patches = ax.hist(x, 50, facecolor='green', alpha=0.75)

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(
    lambda y, pos: '%.0f' % (y * 1e-3)))
ax.set_ylabel('Frequency (000s)')

plt.show()
```

yields
[image]

Comment: is there away to make it 10K,20K,...80K instead?

Comment: @weefwefwqg3: Change `'%.0f'` to `'%.0fK'`

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the values yourself before they are entered. In numpy, you can do just `array/1000` instead of `array`.

Comment: That simply divides each of the values by 1000 -- it doesn't do anything about the frequency values (the frequencies will be the same, just the x axis will be divided by 1000)

Comment: @Jonathan You're right, I spoke a bit too soon. unutbu has a much nicer answer anyway.